# Sql join multiple tables, get count of certain rows, and also check some rows satisfy condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Zoo, each Zoo has many Cages, each Cage has many Animals.

Zoo:

```
+----+
| Id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
```

Cage:

```
+----+-------+
| Id | ZooId |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     1 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  3 |     2 |
|  4 |     2 |
|  5 |     2 |
+----+-------+
```

Animal:

```
+----+--------+----------+
| Id | CageId | IsHungry |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      1 |        0 |
|  2 |      1 |        0 |
|  3 |      1 |        0 |
|  4 |      2 |        1 |
|  5 |      3 |        0 |
|  6 |      4 |        0 |
|  7 |      5 |        0 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

I'm trying to design a query to show each Zoo, the number of cages in that Zoo, and whether or not the Zoo has hungry Animals.

Here is the results I expect:

```
+-------+-----------+--------------+
| ZooID | CageCount | AnyoneHungry |
+-------+-----------+--------------+
|     1 |         2 |            1 |
|     2 |         3 |            0 |
+-------+-----------+--------------+
```

I can get the number of Cages in a Zoo:

```sql
SELECT 
    [c].[ZooId],
    COUNT(*) AS [NumCages]
FROM [Cage] [c]
GROUP BY [c].[ZooId]
ORDER BY [NumCages] DESC
```

I can determine if a Cage has a hungry animal or not:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM [Animal] [a]
    WHERE [a].[CageId] = @CageId AND [a].[IsHungry] = 1
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

But I'm having trouble combining these two into a single query that runs efficiently (in this universe zoos are very popular and have millions of cages and animals).

```sql
SELECT 
    [c].[ZooId], 
    COUNT(*) AS [CageCount], 
    MAX(CONVERT(INT, [x].[AnyoneHungry])) AS [AnyoneHungry]
FROM [Cage] [c]
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT [a].[CageId], MAX(CONVERT(INT, [a].[IsHungry])) AS [AnyoneHungry]
    FROM [Animal] [a]
    GROUP BY [a].[CageId]
) [x] on [x].[CageId] = [c].[Id]
GROUP BY [c].[ZooId]
```

I feel like I'm missing something and it should be possible do run this query using a simpler statement.

Comment: Simplu `SUM(ishungry)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the zoo id and hungry animals:

```
SELECT c.zooid,
       COUNT(DISTINCT C.Id) as CageCount,
       COALESCE(MAX(CONVERT(int, a.IsHungry)), 0) AS AnyHungry
FROM Cage C LEFT JOIN
     Animal A
     ON c.Id = a.CageId AND a.IsHungry = 1
GROUP BY c.zooid;
```

Comment: This query was extremely fast and had a simple execution plan. I had to modify it slightly to include the Cast to int that @el-makki-voundy added in their query.

Comment: @user715374 . . . I don't understand why a `cast()` would be necessary.  What is the data type of `IsHungry`?

Comment: IsHungry is a bit, and sql server gives the following error: 


`Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.`

Comment: @user715374 . . . In that case, you need the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

This should do

```sql
SELECT
    Z.Id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT C.Id) AS CageCount,
    COALESCE(MAX(CAST(A.IsHungry AS INT)), 0) AS AnyHungry /*The cast is only required if A.IsHungry is BIT and not INT*/
FROM Zoo Z
    LEFT JOIN Cage C ON Z.Id = C.ZooId
    LEFT JOIN Animal A ON C.Id = A.CageId
GROUP BY Z.Id
```

Comment: This query grabbed what I needed, it performs much faster if I add the IsHungry predicate to the join statement that @gordon-linoff added.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. The inclusion of the `Zoo` table in the execution plan is only required if you also want zoos without cages in the result.